# Is the X in (LET ((x ...) a fully fleshed symbol?

Tags: common-lisp

Or in other words: Is it possible for a variable in CL not to be (part of) a symbol?

I think I may have a profound misconception about variables in CL.

I always thought CL has no variables, only symbols, and symbols have (among other properties) a name and a value cell (which is the variable). 
And when someone said *"variable `x` has the value 42"* I thought it was short for *"the value cell of the symbol named `x` stores the value 42"*.

But this is probably wrong.

When I type

```
> (let ((a 42))
       (type-of 'a))
SYMBOL
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   The variable A is defined but never used.
```

is the lexical variable `a` in this example a fully fleshed symbol whose value cell has been set to 42?

Because the warning `The variable A is defined but never used` suggests otherwise and it appears that the lexical variable is not the same thing as the symbol `a` in the following form `(type-of 'a)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common Lisp has two data types which have a special meaning for evaluation:

- *cons cells* / *lists*   -> used in Lisp source code, lists are Lisp forms
- *symbols*              -> used as names for various purposes

If you want to use them as data in Lisp code, then you have to quote them.

Both are used in the Lisp source code, but once you compile code, they may disappear.

Variables are written as symbols in the source code. But in compiled code they may go away - when they are *lexical variables*.

Example using SBCL:

a file with

```
(defun test (foo)
  (+ foo foo))
```

Now we do:

```
CL-USER> (proclaim '(optimize (debug 0)))  ; the compiler saves no debug info
; No value
CL-USER> (compile-file "/tmp/test.lisp")
; compiling file "/private/tmp/test.lisp" (written 23 MAY 2017 09:06:51 PM):
; compiling (DEFUN TEST ...)

; /tmp/test.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.013
#P"/private/tmp/test.fasl"
NIL
NIL
CL-USER> (find-symbol "FOO")
FOO
:INTERNAL
```

The compiler has read the source code and created a compiled *FASL* file. We see that the symbol `FOO` is now in the current package. `FOO` names the variable in our source code.

Now quit SBCL and restart it.

Let's load the machine code:

```
CL-USER> (load "/tmp/test")
T
CL-USER> (find-symbol "FOO")
NIL
NIL
```

There is no symbol `FOO` anymore. It's also not possible to retrieve the lexical value of the variable `FOO` using the symbol `FOO`. There is no mapping (like some kind of explicit lexical environment) from symbols to lexical values.

Answer (score 5):

The value cell is used for dynamic (AKA "special") variables, not lexical variables. Lexical variables are symbols in the source code, but they don't have any runtime relationship to the symbol (except for internal use by the debugger).

So if you wrote:

```
(let ((a 42))
  (declare (special a))
  (print (symbol-value 'a)))
```

it would work because the declaration makes it a dynamic variable, and then you can access the value in the function cell.

Comment: So does this mean that lexical variables created by `defun`, `lambda`, `let`, etc. appear to be symbols but, once compiled, in fact aren't?

Comment: They're just symbols in the source code, just as function calls are lists in the source code. When they're compiled, it all turns into machine code, and lexical variables are just stack locations.

Answer (score 2):

You are not checking the type of the bound variable `a` or its value but that of a literal constant symbol that happens to have the same name as the variable in your `let` form:

```
(let ((a 42))
  (type-of 'literal-symbol))
; ==> symbol (since 'literal-symbol evaluates to a symbol, just like 'a does)
```

To check the type of the value of the binding `a` you do it without the literal quote:

```
(let ((a 42))
  (type-of a))
; ==> (integer 0 281474976710655)
```

Here you actually check the type of the let bound value and it's an integer. Surprised that `42` is a number and not a symbol?

```
(let ((a 10) (b 'a))
  (list a b))
; ==> (10 a)
```

The variable `a` and the quoted literal `'a` are not the same. They just happen to look the same when displayed but `'a` is data and `a` is code. In CL a compiler might use lists and symbols internally but what it is when its executing is entirely up to the implementation and in most implementations they stack allocate when they can and the code that evaluate a stack allocated variable would be replaced by something that picks the value at the index from the stack. CL has a `disassemble` function and if you check the output in SBCL from something you'll see it's more similar to the output of a C compiler than the original lisp source.